# EACCES (Permission denied) after granting the necessary permissions

Tags: android, permissions

okay so am having this problem while testing my app on emulator (android 6.0) (since i dont have a android 6.0 device ) at first am asking the user to grant the necessary permission before executing my task and after getting the permission am executing my task but its giving me this error :

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/19FA-1F0B/DCIM/Image1464800718267.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
06-02 12:04:11.906 21595-21595/pb.myPackage D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM                                                                

                                                                ----------beginning of crash
06-02 12:04:11.907 21595-21595/pb.myPackage E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: pb.myPackage, PID: 21595
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pb.myPackage/pb.myPackage.CropActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap$Config android.graphics.Bitmap.getConfig()' on a null object reference
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap$Config android.graphics.Bitmap.getConfig()' on a null object reference
```

my whole code where am asking and then performing my task :

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);

                }else {


                    //Start Activity To Select Image From Gallery
                    Intent gallery_Intent = new Intent(getContext(), GalleryUtil.class);
                    gallery_Intent.putExtra("Switch", 0);
                    startActivityForResult(gallery_Intent, GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE);
                }


            }else {



                //Start Activity To Select Image From Gallery
                Intent gallery_Intent = new Intent(getContext(), GalleryUtil.class);
                gallery_Intent.putExtra("Switch", 0);
                startActivityForResult(gallery_Intent, GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE);

            }
```

as you can see that am checking if the necessary permissions are granted or not but still am getting this exceptions and one most important thing is that this is only happening when i first time performing all of the above task , at first  the user granted the permission am getting this error but when i run the app again from then am not getting any exceptions and everything is working fine

seems like when user is granting the permission this new change  haven't yet updated on the system and after a restart the changes updates get  done and everything gets fine

```
onActivityResult:

    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            String picturePath = data.getStringExtra("picturePath");


            //perform Crop on the Image Selected from Gallery
            performCrop(picturePath);}}

    if (requestCode == RESULT_CROP ) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
            // Set The Bitmap Data To ImageView
            imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);}}
}


private void performCrop(String imageUri) {

    Intent cropIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), CropActivity.class );
    cropIntent.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri);
    startActivity(cropIntent);
    getActivity().finish();
}
```

here after getting the image am sending it for cropping and from there am getting image as a result , and the error is occurring in `CropActivity.class`

galleryClass:

```
public class GalleryUtil extends Activity{
private final static int RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE = 100;
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private static final String TAG = "GalleryUtil";

String mCurrentPhotoPath;
File photoFile = null;
Intent selectedImageIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try{
        //Pick Image From Gallery
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode){
        case RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE:

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                try{


                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    //return Image Path to the Main Activity
                    Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                    returnFromGalleryIntent.putExtra("Switch", false);
                    returnFromGalleryIntent.putExtra("picturePath",picturePath);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK,returnFromGalleryIntent);
                    finish();



                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnFromGalleryIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            }else{
                Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_CANCELED");
                Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnFromGalleryIntent);
                finish();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

cropActivity :

```
    public class CropActivity extends Activity {


    File savedFile;
    Button btnCancel;
    Context context;
    PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;


    Bitmap mImage;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.new_crop_actvity);


            final CropImageView cropImageView = (CropImageView)findViewById(R.id.cropImageView);
            final ImageView croppedImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.croppedImageView);
            final  ImageView  bgImgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.blurBGImgView);

            btnCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

            context = this.getBaseContext();






            mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(croppedImageView);

            Uri imgUri1 = Uri.parse(getIntent().getExtras().getString("imageUri"));

            String UriStr = imgUri1.toString();


            File f = new File(UriStr);
            final String filePath = f.getPath();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            cropImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


            Bitmap blurredBitmap = Blur.fastblur(this, bitmap, 20);

            bgImgView.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap);


            cropImageView.setCropMode(CropImageView.CropMode.CIRCLE);



            //customising crop activity
            cropImageView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
            cropImageView.setOverlayColor(0xAA1C1C1C);
            cropImageView.setFrameColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
            cropImageView.setHandleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
            cropImageView.setGuideColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));


            // Set image for cropping
            //cropImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

            //cropImageView.setImageBitmap(mImage);


            Button cropButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.crop_button);
            cropButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //  Bitmap CroppedIamge = cropImageView.getCroppedBitmap();
                    // Get cropped image, and show result.
                    croppedImageView.setImageBitmap(cropImageView.getCroppedBitmap());



                    View content = croppedImageView;
                    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();

//
//                    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
//                    File file = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/img.jpg");


                  //  File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File file = new File(context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/img.gpj");



                    String path = file.getPath();
//                    File file = new File("/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, ostream);


                        savedFile = new File(path);


                        ostream.close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }


                    croppedImageView.buildDrawingCache();
                    Bitmap CroppedIamge = croppedImageView.getDrawingCache();


                   Intent sendCroppedImgIntent = new Intent(CropActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    //extras.putParcelable("imagebitmap", CroppedIamge);
                    extras.putString("croppedImgUri", savedFile.toString() );
                    extras.putInt("Switch",1);
                    sendCroppedImgIntent.putExtras(extras);
                    startActivity(sendCroppedImgIntent);




                }
            });
        }


    public void cancel(View view) {

        Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(CropActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(cancelIntent);

    }
}
```

Comment: have you overide  `public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)`

Comment: no @SohailZahid but how its gonna change the scenario ?  please  let me know

Comment: because already from the permission dialogue am able to  grant the permission then what to do with this results ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ActivityName.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);

            } else {

                Intent gallery_Intent = new Intent(getContext(), GalleryUtil.class);
                gallery_Intent.putExtra("Switch", 0);
                startActivityForResult(gallery_Intent, GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE);
            }
        } else {
            //Start Activity To Select Image From Gallery
            Intent gallery_Intent = new Intent(getContext(), GalleryUtil.class);
            gallery_Intent.putExtra("Switch", 0);
            startActivityForResult(gallery_Intent, GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE);
        }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
                final int numOfRequest = grantResults.length;
                final boolean isGranted = numOfRequest == 1
                        && PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == grantResults[numOfRequest - 1];
                if (isGranted) {
                    Intent gallery_Intent = new Intent(getContext(), GalleryUtil.class);
                    gallery_Intent.putExtra("Switch", 0);
                    startActivityForResult(gallery_Intent, GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE);
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Comment: well i appreciate your effort bro , but can you please explain  how overriding `onRequestPermissionsResult` is gonna help me with this problem ??

Comment: this will confirm that weather you got permission or not?

Comment: so ?  things are not going to change bro because i already know that i got the permission  , am doing a check at first though  , well i even tried your solution which kinda not making any sense in this scenario and am still left with the same error

Comment: why this is important `onRequestPermissionsResult` when user get permission by allow then he will exist app then again open to use that feature `onRequestPermissionsResult` will help us to do task in same session.And post you `onActivityResult` too by updating question.

Comment: here you go , @sohail

Comment: hey @sohail sorry i thought am editing my question , ended up editing your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113596/discussion-between-sohail-zahid-and-remy-boys).